# ionic Facebook authentification error "cordova_not_available"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make login with Facebook OAuth using `ionic` but I have a problem when I click Facebook login button show me the error `cordova_not_available`
here is the error :

[image]

if I use the app in production release build on android the same problem with Google OAuth

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';

    private fb: Facebook,

  facebookLogin() {
this.fb.getLoginStatus().then((res: any) => {
  if (res.status == 'connected') {
    console.log("user connected already" + res.authResponse.accessToken);
    this.createAccount(res.authResponse.accessToken, 'fb');

  }
  else {
    console.log("USer Not login ");
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
        // this.alert.show('Logged into Facebook!' + JSON.stringify(res));
        console.log("successfully login ");
        this.createAccount(res.authResponse.accessToken, 'fb');
      })
      .catch(e => this.shared.showAlert('Error logging into Facebook' + JSON.stringify(e)));
  }
}).catch(e => this.shared.showAlert('Error Check Login Status Facebook' + JSON.stringify(e)));
```

}

Comment: Your plugin is not getting copied to the native side.. run `ionic cordova prepare android --prod`, if this does not work, delete your android folder and then again run this command..

Answer (score 0):

try to remove and reinstall the plugin, then execute `ionic repair`